# Local variable undefined in my main

Tags: java

I'm in my intro to Java class and working on loops this week.  I think I have the loop built but my variable within my main ***CommissionNotifications*** is undefined.

I think I have to create an object and reference the variable stored in my other class...am I on the right track?

The program asks for annual sales and then calculates there commission payment based upon the bracket they fall into.  The commission payment is done through a If statement on the class and then the program displays what they could earn if they increased there sales by 5,000 up to 1.5 * of there sales.  IE if they earn 100000 in sales the table should display there initial commission and then what they could earn if they increased there sales to 150000(1.5*)

Here is my class:

```
public class Calculations {

     double TotalSales;      
     double ComRate = 0.025;         
     double AnnualSal = 80000;       
     double compensation;
     double SalesTarget;
     double Acceleration = 1.5;
     double chart;
     double ComAccFactor;



    public double getCommissionNotifications() {
        return CommissionNotifications;
    }

    public void setCommissionNotifications(double commissionNotifications) {
        CommissionNotifications = commissionNotifications;
    }

    public double CommissionNotifications; {

         if (TotalSales > 120000){

             CommissionNotifications = AnnualSal  + (TotalSales * (ComRate + Acceleration));
         } else if (TotalSales > SalesTarget * .8) {

           CommissionNotifications = AnnualSal + (TotalSales * ComRate);

         } else {;

             CommissionNotifications = AnnualSal;

         }
    }
}
```

***Here is my Main***

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;



public class Paycheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

            System.out.println("Enter Total Commission Sales:  ");  
            double TotalSales = input.nextDouble();                 

            double Base = TotalSales;
            double finish = TotalSales * 1.5;

            System.out.println("Your Total compensation with your annual sales is:  " + getCommissionNotifications);

            int i = Base + 5000;

            while (i <= finish) {

                System.out.println(Base);

                TotalSales += 5000;
         }

    }

}
```

Comment: `getCommissionNotifications` is a method within a different class, and you're using it in `main` as if it were a variable. You should be calling it on an instance of `Calculations`. Although your `Calculations` class is odd as well, in terms of having an instance initializer which is doing work that I suspect a method should be doing...

Comment: `public double CommissionNotifications; {` Are you trying to make that a variable or a method?

Comment: Thank you - i thought that i would need to call the method from my calculations class but when i tried it last night before posting this it wasn't working.  I will try again.

Comment: to answer your questions Commission notifications should be a method..how would i write that differently to be a method and thank you for the feedback as I'm only a week into learning java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code looks a lot like C# with the capitalized variable names. Anyways, your 
`getCommissionNotifications` method should handle the logic of what to `return` based on `TotalSales`. It's also not clear why you need a setter method, so I've commented that out.

As for using the below class, you need an instance of the `Calculations` class

```
Calculations calc = new Calculations();
double TotalSales = input.nextDouble();                 
calc.TotalSales = TotalSales;

// double Base = TotalSales; // Duplicate variable not needed
double finish = TotalSales * 1.5;

System.out.println("Your Total compensation with your annual sales is:  " + calc.getCommissionNotifications());
```

```
public class Calculations {

     double TotalSales;      
     double ComRate = 0.025;         
     double AnnualSal = 80000;       
     double compensation;
     double SalesTarget;
     double Acceleration = 1.5;
     double chart;
     double ComAccFactor;

    public double getCommissionNotifications() {
         if (TotalSales > 120000){
             return AnnualSal  + (TotalSales * (ComRate + Acceleration));
         } else if (TotalSales > SalesTarget * .8) {
             return AnnualSal + (TotalSales * ComRate);
         } else {
             return AnnualSal;
         }
    }

    // Not sure why this is needed... You have a dynamic getter method

    //public void setCommissionNotifications(double commissionNotifications) {
    //    CommissionNotifications = commissionNotifications;
    //}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback - the things you called out are me a week into learning java and still wrapping my head around variable scope and how you can call a variable from various classes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`getCommisionNotifications` is a member of class `Calculations`. To access it you will need to create a new `Calculations` object:

```
Calculations c = new Calculations();
c.getCommisionNotifications();
```

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks - edited my answer and I learned something today!

Comment: it was the second line c.getCommissionNotifications(); that I was missing when i tried to create the object before posting. @nhouser9

Comment: @DavidCurtis No problem! If this helped please remember to upvote / accept as answer.